# Ember {include: property} and Strongloop

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, strongloop

Ok, here is the thing, as I dig more into Ember and StrongLoop integration I find it more and more difficult to connect them both.

I have the following problem now. StrongLoop does not return the model relations based on JSONAPI format, so if my `video` model has a `hasMany` relationship with `tag` model, there will not be an `include` array in my response as specified here: [JSON API docs](http://jsonapi.org/examples/).

So I have to options here: either `async: true` which makes 2 requests and is not desirable, or pass a filter parameter to the request like:

`return this.store.queryRecord('video', {'include': 'tag'});` which will cast a request to `/videos?include=tag` but StrongLoop doesn't recognise this request.

Any thoughts?

Comment: aren't you going to have to create your own Ember data adapter (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html) to map your js ember calls on the ember store onto the appropriate http calls for strongloop?

Comment: @stevejpurves well I was trying to take the maximum Ember offers built-in. The response is in `JSONAPI` and the endpoints as well. If I won't be able to adjust these small differences then yes, I will make my custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

To format StrongLoop responses as json:api, install the excellent [loopback-component-jsonapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-jsonapi) and create a `server/component-config.json` file with

```
{
  "loopback-component-jsonapi": {}
}
```

I like camel-case ReST apis, so I configured the Ember JSONAPIAdapter like this

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({

  // Where our API lives on our URI
  namespace: 'api',

  // change default from dasherize to camelize
  pathForType(type) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(camelized);
  }
});
```

After adding a `tags: hasMany('tag')` to your Ember video model, because the relationships links are in the response, you can:

```
{{#each model.tags as |tag|}}
...
{{/each}}
```

Of course, this method will make a separate ajax request for each tags - may work in some cases, not in others.

StrongLoop developed their filter syntax before the json:api standard so it is a little different. Their filters must include the `filter` query param key. I prefer using json because it is easier to read and works well with Ember.

```
var query = {filter: {where: {createdBy:'starver', 
                              updatedBy:'service_acct'},
                      limit: 30
            }};
return this.store.query('mymodel', query);
```

If you have query params passed into your route, you can pass use them in your filter, assuming they are constructed to work with loopback:

```
model(params) {
  var query = {filter: {where: params,
                        limit: 45
              }};
  return this.store.query('subscription', query);
}
```

Side-loading data in StrongLoop looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/subscriptions/1475?filter[include]=subscriptionStatus
```

In ember, you can pass a string as a query, but v2.7.0 broke this functionality. There is a work around: disable query param sorting in your JSONAPIAdapter config:

```
  // prevent the default implementation from turning a string into an array
  sortQueryParams: function(params) {
    return params;
  }
```

Then your route model query looks like:

```
return this.store.query('view', 'filter[include]=tag');
```

jQuery mangles more complex query filters when passed as objects - it decomposes the filter object into a series of filter query params which does not make any sense to StrongLoop. One way to work around this is to form your query filter as a js object and then JSON.stringify() it.

Using the JSON.stringify() approach, another way to include data from one table into another is to include that data in the attributes section of your response. Here is an example from working code:

```
var query = {
  include: {
    relation: "subscriptionStatus",
    scope: {
      fields: ["subscriptionStatus"],
      where: {
        endDate: null
      }
    }
  },
  limit: 45
};
return this.store.query('subscription', 'filter=' + JSON.stringify(query));
```

This produces an attributes section that looks like

```
"attributes": {
  "createdBy": "services",
  "createdTs": "2016-07-27T21:37:50.000Z",
  "updatedBy": "services",
  "updatedTs": "2016-07-27T21:58:04.000Z",
  "version": 9,
  "certificateId": 1,
  "backupTime": "0:0",
  "backupRetentionDays": 1,
  "subscriptionStatus": [
    {
      "subscriptionStatus": "TERMINATED",
      "subscriptionId": 1475
    }
  ]
},
```

This is interesting, but presents some name collision problems in ember conventions.

This is a pretty old question, but perhaps it will help someone struggling with these issues.

StrongLoop query doc: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data#Queryingdata-UsingstringifiedJSONinRESTqueries

NOTE: I am using loopback v2.14.0, ember v2.7.0 (worked in 2.5, 2.6 as well)